# Screen Modes not Running in Proper Order

Tags: python, object, pygame

I am having trouble displaying my proper screens in the right order. I first want the Title screen, which is red. Then, if I click the Play Button, I want to switch to the Difficulty Screen, which has Easy and Hard Buttons. If I click the easy button, I want my game to go to main game, which I think I have done by passing in pong4.main() into my action parameter for the button.

My problem is that I'm running the main game first instead of the Title Screen. I never do hit the title screen. Then, once the game of pong is finished, I'm also getting a font

```
import pygame
import os 
import pongtry4


WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREY = (200, 200, 200)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 400))
pygame.init()

###############################
class Button():
    def __init__(self, txt, location, action, bg=WHITE, fg=BLACK, size=(80, 30), font_name="Segoe Print", font_size=16):
        self.color = bg  # the static (normal) color
        self.bg = bg  # actual background color, can change on mouseover
        self.fg = fg  # text color
        self.size = size

        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont(font_name, font_size)
        self.txt = txt
        self.txt_surf = self.font.render(self.txt, 1, self.fg)
        self.txt_rect = self.txt_surf.get_rect(center=[s//2 for s in self.size])

        self.surface = pygame.surface.Surface(size)
        self.rect = self.surface.get_rect(center=location)

        self.call_back_ = action

    def draw(self):
        self.mouseover()

        self.surface.fill(self.bg)
        self.surface.blit(self.txt_surf, self.txt_rect)
        screen.blit(self.surface, self.rect)

    def mouseover(self):
        self.bg = self.color
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if self.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            self.bg = GREY  # mouseover color

    def call_back(self):
        self.call_back_()


def my_great_function():
    print("Great! " * 5)


def my_fantastic_function():
    print("Fantastic! " * 4)


def mousebuttondown(button):
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    if button.rect.collidepoint(pos):
        button.call_back()
#########################


class SceneBase:
    def __init__(self):
        self.next = self

    def ProcessInput(self, events, pressed_keys):
        print("uh-oh, you didn't override this in the child class")

    def Update(self):
        print("uh-oh, you didn't override this in the child class")

    def Render(self, screen):
        print("uh-oh, you didn't override this in the child class")

    def SwitchToScene(self, next_scene):
        self.next = next_scene

    def Terminate(self):
        self.SwitchToScene(None)

def run_game(width, height, fps, starting_scene):

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    active_scene = starting_scene


    while active_scene != None:
        pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        # Event filtering 
        filtered_events = []
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            quit_attempt = False
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit_attempt = True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                alt_pressed = pressed_keys[pygame.K_LALT] or \
                              pressed_keys[pygame.K_RALT]
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    quit_attempt = True
                elif event.key == pygame.K_F4 and alt_pressed:
                    quit_attempt = True

            if quit_attempt:
                active_scene.Terminate()
            else:
                filtered_events.append(event)

        active_scene.ProcessInput(filtered_events, pressed_keys)
        active_scene.Update()
        active_scene.Render(screen)

        active_scene = active_scene.next

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(fps)

# The rest is code where you implement your game using the Scenes model 

class TitleScene(SceneBase):
    def __init__(self):
        SceneBase.__init__(self)
        #Create buttons and font instances here 
        self.play_button = Button("Play", (60, 30), self.SwitchToScene(DifficultyScene()))
        self.my_font = pygame.font.SysFont("Moyko", 50)

    def ProcessInput(self, events, pressed_keys):
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                # Move to the next scene when the user pressed Enter 
                self.SwitchToScene(DifficultyScene())

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                print("You are hitting up!") 
                print(self.next)

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mousebuttondown(self.play_button)

    def Update(self):
        pass

    def Render(self, screen):
        # For the sake of brevity, the title scene is a blank red screen 
        screen.fill((255, 0, 0))

        #Just Draw the Text Here 
        #myfont = pygame.font.SysFont(("Moyko"), 50)
        textImage = self.my_font.render("Anime Pong", True, (0, 255, 0))
        screen.blit(textImage, (100,100))

        #Just draw the button here 
        self.play_button.draw()


def my_great_function():
    print("Great! " * 5)


def my_fantastic_function():
    print("Fantastic! " * 4)


class DifficultyScene(SceneBase):
    def __init__(self):
        SceneBase.__init__(self)

        self.easy_button = Button("Easy", (60, 30), pongtry4.main())
        self.hard_button = Button("Hard", (120, 60), my_fantastic_function)


    def ProcessInput(self, events, pressed_keys):

        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                # Move to the next scene when the user pressed Enter 
                self.SwitchToScene(GameScene())

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                print("You are hitting up!") 
                print(self.next)

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mousebuttondown(self.easy_button)
                mousebuttondown(self.hard_button)

    def Update(self):
        pass

    def Render(self, screen):
        # The game scene is just a blank blue screen 
        screen.fill((255, 0, 255))

        self.easy_button.draw()
        self.hard_button.draw()

class GameScene(SceneBase):
    def __init__(self):
        SceneBase.__init__(self)

    def ProcessInput(self, events, pressed_keys):
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                # Move to the next scene when the user pressed Enter 
                self.SwitchToScene(DifficultyScene())

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                print("You are hitting up!") 
                print(self.next)

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mousebuttondown(self.play_button)

    def Update(self):
        pass

    def Render(self, screen):
        # The game scene is just a blank blue screen 
        screen.fill((0, 0, 255))

run_game(800, 400, 60, TitleScene())
```

Below is also my pongTry4 Main Game Model

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import * 
import math 
import random


########Colors######
RED = (255,0,0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
BLACK = (0, 0 , 0)
####################

game_mode = "Easy"

class Pong(object):

    def __init__(self, screen_size):
        #screenSize is a tuple (XLen, YLen)
        self.screen_size = screen_size  

        self.XCenter = screen_size[0] // 2
        self.YCenter = screen_size[1] // 2

        self.rad = 10 

        #Create the surface for the Pong. #Drawn from top left corner 
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.XCenter-self.rad,
                                self.YCenter-self.rad,
                                self.rad*2,
                                self.rad*2)
        self.color = GREEN

        #direction and speed 
        self.direction = [-1, -1]
        self.speedX = 4
        self.speedY = 2


        #Pong Hitting left edge results in a loss
        #Pong Hitting right edge results in a win
        self.hit_left_edge = False 
        self.hit_right_edge = False 


    def update(self, player_paddle, ai_paddle):

        self.XCenter += self.speedX * self.direction[0]
        self.YCenter += self.speedY * self.direction[1]

        #update the center of the rectangle 
        self.rect.center = (self.XCenter, self.YCenter)

        #Make sure the ball does not go past the bottom/top of screen
        if self.rect.top <= 0:
            self.direction[1] = 1
        elif self.rect.bottom >= self.screen_size[1] - 1:
            self.direction[1] = -1 

        #Tells us if the right or left edge has been hit
        #This will tell us if someone has scored or not 
        if self.rect.left <= 0:
            self.hit_left_edge = True 
        elif self.rect.right >= self.screen_size[0] - 1:
            self.hit_right_edge = True 

        #Change the direction of pong based on where it hits player paddle

        if self.rect.colliderect(player_paddle.rect):

            relative_IntersectionY = player_paddle.YCenter - self.YCenter
            normal_IntersectionY = relative_IntersectionY // (player_paddle.height //2)
            bounce_angle = normal_IntersectionY * (math.pi * 5 // 12)   

            #constrains the speed of the ball
            if self.speedX >= 10 or self.speedY >= 10:
                self.speedX -= random.randint(4, 7)
                self.speedY -= random.randint(4, 7)

            self.speedX += random.randint(1, 3)
            self.speedY += random.randint(1, 3)
            print(self.speedX, self.speedY)
            self.direction[0] = math.cos(bounce_angle)
            self.direction[1] = -1*math.sin(bounce_angle)

        #Change the direction of pong baesd on where it hits AI Paddle 
        if self.rect.colliderect(ai_paddle.rect):
            relative_IntersectionY = ai_paddle.YCenter - self.YCenter
            normal_IntersectionY = relative_IntersectionY // (ai_paddle.height // 2)
            bounce_angle = normal_IntersectionY * (math.pi * 5 //12)

            if self.speedX >= 10 or self.speedY >= 10:
                self.speedX -= random.randint(4, 7)
                self.speedY -= random.randint(4, 7)

            self.speedX += random.randint(1,2)
            self.speedY += random.randint(1,2)
            print(self.speedX, self.speedY)

            self.direction[0] = -1 * math.cos(bounce_angle)
            self.direction[1] = -1 * math.sin(bounce_angle)


    def draw(self, screen):

        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, self.rect.center, self.rad, 0)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLACK, self.rect.center, self.rad, 1)

class Paddle(object):

    def __init__(self, screen_size, XCenter, YCenter, height, width, color):

        self.screen_size = screen_size
        self.XCenter = XCenter
        self.YCenter = YCenter
        self.height = height
        self.width = width 
        self.color = color 


        #Create the paddle surface on the sides of the screen
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, self.YCenter - self.height//2, self.width, self.height)


    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.rect, 0)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, self.rect, 1)


class PlayerPaddle(Paddle):

    def __init__(self, screen_size, XCenter, YCenter, height, width, color):

        super().__init__(screen_size, XCenter, YCenter, height, width, color)

        self.speed = 5
        self.direction = 0

    def draw(self, screen):

        super().draw(screen)

    def update(self):

        self.YCenter += self.direction * self.speed 

        self.rect.center = (self.XCenter, self.YCenter)

        #ensures the paddle doesn't go off the screen 
        if self.rect.top <= 0:
            self.rect.top = 0
        if self.rect.bottom > self.screen_size[1]:
            self.rect.bottom = self.screen_size[1]

class AIPaddle(Paddle):

    def __init__(self, screen_size, XCenter, YCenter, height, width, color):

        super().__init__(screen_size, XCenter, YCenter, height, width, color)

        self.speed = 4

    def draw(self, screen):

        super().draw(screen)

    def update(self, pong):

        #If the pong is above the paddle, move the paddle towards it
        #If the pong is below the paddle, move the paddle towards it 
        if pong.rect.top < self.rect.top:
            self.YCenter -= self.speed 
        elif pong.rect.bottom > self.rect.bottom:
            self.YCenter += self.speed  

        #update the AI Paddle's center coordinates 
        self.rect.center = (self.XCenter, self.YCenter)

################################################

def main():

    pygame.init()
    screen_size = (1200, 800)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    pong = Pong(screen_size)
    ai_paddle = AIPaddle(screen_size, screen_size[0] - 5, screen_size[1]//2, 100, 10, WHITE)
    player_paddle = PlayerPaddle(screen_size, 5, screen_size[1]//2, 100, 10, WHITE)

    running = True

    while running:
        #fps limiting/reporting phase
        clock.tick(64)

        #event handling phase
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                running = False

            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_UP:
                    player_paddle.direction = -1
                elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                    player_paddle.direction = 1
            if event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == K_UP and player_paddle.direction == -1:
                    player_paddle.direction = 0
                elif event.key == K_DOWN and player_paddle.direction == 1:
                    player_paddle.direction = 0

        #object updating phase
        ai_paddle.update(pong)
        player_paddle.update()
        pong.update(player_paddle, ai_paddle)

        #CODE TASK: make some text on the screen over everything else saying you lost/won, and then exit on keypress
        #CODE BONUS: allow restarting of the game (hint: you can recreate the Pong/Paddle objects the same way we made them initially)
        if pong.hit_left_edge:
            print("You Won")
            running = False
        elif pong.hit_right_edge:
            print("you lose")
            running = False

        #rendering phase
        screen.fill((100,100,100))

        ai_paddle.draw(screen)
        player_paddle.draw(screen)
        pong.draw(screen)

        pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.quit()
```

is there a problem when I'm running main(), or running run_game(), or is it more of a problem of passing in main() into one of the parameters of my button if it is clicked? Thanks

Comment: always use tag `python` - it highlights code and makes it more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Buttons in most frameworks expect `callback` - it means function name without `()` and parameters - so you need `pong4.main` instead of `pong4.main()`

If you use `pong4.main()` then you get something like

```
result = pong4.main()
Button(..., result)
```

so it executes `pong4.main()` as first.

---

**EDIT:** You have the same problem in

```
Button("Play", (60, 30), self.SwitchToScene(DifficultyScene()))
```

You have to create function and use it button

```
def function():
    self.SwitchToScene(DifficultyScene())

Button("Play", (60, 30), function)
```

or you can use `lambda` to create noname function

```
Button("Play", (60, 30), lambda:self.SwitchToScene(DifficultyScene()) )
```

Comment: Part of my problem has been fixed in that when I click Easy Mode, the pong game runs. However, the very first thing that pops up is still the pong game, and the title screen never enters.

Comment: maybe you used `()` in other button.

Comment: you have the same problem in `Button("Play", (60, 30), self.SwitchToScene(DifficultyScene()))`

Comment: see `lambda` in my answer.

Comment: That fixed the title scene error. However, I'm still having two more errors. First, this Scene Code is always running an old version of my pongTry4 File and never the edited versions of my pongTry4.

My second problem is that the main pong game still runs before the title screen.

Comment: I fixed the second problem, but I'm still having the first problem.

Comment: maybe you have new `pongTry4` in wrong place and it can find only old one. I have no problem with code.